# Cloudformation dynamic variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm building a cloud formation template that deploys a vpc, igw, subnets and security groups. Everything is constant except for the second octet in the CIDR block. This will change per region.

```
Parameters:
  ClusterId:
    Type: String
    Description: Cluster ID

Resources:

  #### VPC ####

  VPC:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPC'
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Sub "10.${ClusterId}.0.0/16"
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true

  #### Subnets ####

  InfrastructureSubnetPrivateA:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::Subnet"
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [0, !GetAZs ]
      CidrBlock: !Sub "10.${ClusterId}.0.0/24"
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: infrastructure-subnet-private-a
        - Key: Group
          Value: infrastructure

  #### Security Groups ####

  SecurityGroup1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Security Group 1
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - CidrIp: !GetAtt InfrastructureSubnetPrivateA.CidrBlock
          IpProtocol: -1
```

Problem: CidrIp under the security group requires a Cidr block. It doesn't accept the current format using !GetAtt. Is there a way to dynamically create and use a variable in Cloudformation? What other options do I have?

I tried !GetAtt but cfn-lint complains about it not being acceptable with the following message.

"Invalid GetAtt for InfrastructureSubnetPrivateA.CidrBlock for resource SecurityGroup1"

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Sorry if this is obvious, but have you tried just using the same value you used for the subnet? (i.e. `!Sub "10.${ClusterId}.0.0/24"`)?

Comment: What is the actual value of `ClusterId` that you use?

Comment: !Sub works but then I'll have to define that same cidr block twice which I'm trying to avoid. @TofigHasanov

Comment: @Marcin The cluster id could be anything between 2-250. I'm currently using 8.

Answer (score 1):

There is **nothing wrong** with the template. I just copied it and pasted, and just deployed with `8` for `ClusterId` with any warnings, issues or problems.

Comment: thank you! You're right. It works. The actual problem is the cfn-lint which throws an error but cloudformation template worked the way I have it.  I just didn't try running it before posting the question here.